# Send Shortcut Events to Child Views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WPF Window with several inner child views. Sometimes I swap these views, change tabs to other views and even open new windows with new views.

Most of the views do the same stuff, adding some new item, so I wanted to make a shortcut that will trigger a command on the current active `ViewModel` of the current active `View`.

I was hopping to make something like this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control"
                Key="A"
                Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Just once and have the `MainViewModel` send the command to the current active `ViewModel`.

The problem is the shortcut works fine at startup, but as soon as I click on an inner child view the shorcut never fires again, only if I click on the window's menu it works back again.

I am pretty sure this is related to `focus`, but I don't know how to solve this. My main goal is to avoid have to repeat this lines of code for every single one of my child views.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: show us more code about your viewmodel and where do you want to access the shortcut

Comment: I believe I can't make it, the code is huge, I have some 15 child ViewModels and the main ViewModel governs all of them.  The idea is to have the same command on all the ViewModels and expose it in an interface so the MainViewModel can use that interface to call the command once the shortcut triggers its command. The problem is the command isn't being triggered once the focus is on some child view, inside a tab control for example, not defined in the MainWindow.xaml